# Build Fail arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c++, c, makefile, stm32

I got into the book "Beginning STM32" - Warren Gay. 
I tried to build the sources under Cygwin, but even if the path to the required files is denoted in the makefile, the required files were not found.The file in the folders **libopencm3/cm3/scb.h** lays in the path: **/home/root/STM32/stm32f103c8t6/libopencm3/include** so the correct path should be **/home/root/STM32/stm32f103c8t6/libopencm3/include/libopencm3/cm3/scb.h** and I checked the presence of the files.

So I tried to change the #include into #include "file.h" with the required header file in the source folder - this worked, but there are a lot of cases in different source files.

Is there any suggestion to get this fixed or to find a way to get out of this?

Thanks a lot!

This is what I got from the terminal.

```
[~/STM32/stm32f103c8t6]

$ make

make -C rtos/libwwg


make[1]: Entering directory '/home/root/STM32/stm32f103c8t6/rtos/libwwg'
make -w -C ./src

make[2]: Entering directory '/home/root/STM32/stm32f103c8t6/rtos/libwwg/src'
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Os -g -std=c99 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -msoft-float -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd -Wextra -Wshadow -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -I/home/root/STM32/stm32f103c8t6/libopencm3/include -I/home/root/STM32/stm32f103c8t6//rtos/libwwg/include -I./rtos -I. -MD -Wall -Wundef -DSTM32F1 -I/home/root/STM32/stm32f103c8t6/libopencm3/include -I/home/root/STM32/stm32f103c8t6//rtos/libwwg/include -o usbcdc.o -c usbcdc.c

usbcdc.c:7:10: fatal error: libopencm3/cm3/scb.h: No such file or directory
7 | #include <libopencm3/cm3/scb.h>
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

make[2]: *** [../../../Makefile.incl:111: usbcdc.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/root/STM32/stm32f103c8t6/rtos/libwwg/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:8: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/root/STM32/stm32f103c8t6/rtos/libwwg'
make: *** [Makefile:41: libwwg] Error 2
```

Comment: I would advice to do not to do it this way. I would also discourage you from using this library. The best choice is bare-metal programming. If you want HAL use STM HAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I know what is the source of the problem.
There are problems in Cygwin with the path format or rather between the interaction between the Windows and Linux path formats. I could solve the problem by changing the paths in the Makefile from the Linux /home/folder to the Windows D:\home\folder\ format.

Answer (score 0):

more detailed answer beginners:
modifying 2 lines at "Makefile.incl" may solve the problem.
"Makefile.incl" is suppose to be in ~/STM32/stm32f103c8t6 folder in above case.

Following are the lines in "Makefile.incl"

---

#TOP_DIR    := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

---

TOP_DIR     := C:\xyz\home\STM32\stm32f103c8t6

---

#OPENCM3_DIR    := $(abspath $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))/libopencm3)

---

OPENCM3_DIR     := c:/xyz/home/STM32/stm32f103c8t6/libopencm3

---

'\' or '/' in path doesn't matter